# Change background in the same frame

Tags: beamer, templates

I was wondering whether would be possible to change the background in the same frame. I mean something like the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate{background}{back1}{--some stuff--}
\defbeamertemplate{background}{back2}{--other stuff--}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{background}[back1]
\begin{frame}{Title}
\only<2->{\setbeamertemplate{background}[back2]}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a very good question! Can you add a bit more information on what the purpose of the different backgrounds is? Maybe there is some alternative approach. Not pretty, but you could use a background depending on the page number: `\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \ifnum\thepage=1
    some stuff
  \else
    other stuff
  \fi
}` (replace 1 with the page number of the first slide in the frame)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz As far as my case is concerned, I have some `\tikz` to include in the background. An alternative approach would be to use `overlay`. I was looking for a more general solution. (Your one is working, but as you change the order of frames you have to change the number)

Comment: I would definitely approach this from the tikz side and not via the background template. Either by the `overlay` you mentioned or via tikz layers, depending on the situation.